# InAppBilling v3 IabResult response code BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

Following the docs on developer site , i have implemented InAppBilling v3 in my app recently . I have used the classes in the utils package provided in the **TRIVIAL DRIVE** sample.

The problem i am facing is if a user has purchased an in app product already on launching purchse flow again on another device the play store dialog shows **ITEM ALREADY OWNED** but the response code returned by **IabResult** does not match to the constant **IabHelper.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED** . The response code returned is actually one of the error codes in IabHelper class (-1005 User cancelled).

I would really like to know how can i get the actual response code instead of error code. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code for callback

```
// Callback for when a purchase is finished
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener =
        new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {

                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    if (result.getResponse() ==
                            IabHelper.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
                        //already owned
                        boolean isPremium = true;
                        SharedPrefsUtils.setPremium(BaseActivity.this, isPremium);
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(new InAppBillingUiUpdateEvent(isPremium));
                        //setWaitScreen(false);
                        return;
                    }
                    //handle error
                    complain(result.getResponse() + " " + "Error purchasing: " + result);
                    //setWaitScreen(false);
                    return;
                }
                if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
                    //corrupted
                    complain("Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
                    //setWaitScreen(false);
                    return;
                }

                //successful
                if (purchase.getSku().equals(NO_ADS_PRODUCT_ID)) {
                    // bought the premium upgrade!
                    alert("Thank you for upgrading to premium!");
                    boolean isPremium = true;
                    SharedPrefsUtils.setPremium(BaseActivity.this, isPremium);
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new InAppBillingUiUpdateEvent(isPremium));
                    //setWaitScreen(false);
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 4):

I finally managed to find the problem in the **IabHelper** code , So here it goes whenever an **Activity.RESULT_CANCELED** result code is returned in **handleActivityResult** method the **IabResult** for all such cases is fixed with **user cancelled (-1005)** no matter what the reason is. So in order to get the correct actual response code replace the following code in **handleActivityResult**

```
 else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        logDebug("Purchase canceled - Response: " + getResponseDesc(responseCode));
        result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_USER_CANCELLED, "User canceled.");
        if (mPurchaseListener != null) mPurchaseListener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
    }
```

with this

```
 else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        logDebug("Purchase canceled - Response: " + getResponseDesc(responseCode));
        result = new IabResult(responseCode, null);
        if (mPurchaseListener != null) mPurchaseListener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
    }
```

hope it will saves someones time